# How to read alternating lines of text in a file to separate arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, input, eol

The assignment is to make a test grader. The first line of the file is all the answers
and the next lines alternate between a students name (LAST, FIRST) and they're answers on the following line. I'm able to pass in the test key answers but when I try to use the getline() function, it doesn't store the value to the first index of the array and cin.ignore() just causes my program to freeze. Where do i go from here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef char answerKey[30];
typedef string studentNames[25];

int main()
{

    fstream inFile;

    inFile.open("xfile.txt");
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR FILE NOT FOUND" << endl;
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            inFile >> answerKey[i];

        getline(inFile, studentNames[0]);

        cout << studentNames[0];  
    }
}
```

The output is null.

Comment: try operations on `inFile` instead of `cin`.  `cin` is `stdin` ie: the Console you can type into while program is running.  `cin.ignore()` will pause until you hit enter on the command line while it's running.  Try `inFile.getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

When alternating between formatted and unformatted I/O you typically need to get rid of leading whitespace! The formatted input (i.e. when using `operator>>()`) skips leading whitespace (you can turn that off using `std::noskipws` but it is rarely useful). On the other hand, unformatted input, e.g., `std::getline()`, doesn't skip leading whitespace. Since the formatted input for numbers stops the moment there is a non-number in the stream, e.g., on a space or a newline, the whitespace is still there when `std::getline()` is called: the end of line with the answers is clearly indicated by a newline. `std::getline()` will stop on this very newline which probably means that no characters are being stored and only the newline gets extracted.

The easiest way to consume leading whitespace is to use the `std::ws` manipulator, e.g.:

```
if (std::getline(inFile >> std::ws, studentNames[0])) {
    // process the student name
}
```

(since input can always fail, I can't bring myself to omit the check for a successful input).

If you want better control, e.g., to skip whitespace up to and including a newline but not any whitespace after that, you'll need a custom approach to skip whitespace. It isn't really hard to do either, though.